# Replace part of an image with another in C# with WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, image

I have a big .PNG that has many little images on it. I want to replace part of the big image with a smaller one. So at X and Y coordinates, that part of the image will be replaced starting from the top left hand corner, while still leaving the rest of the original image intact.

I have been reading about the Graphics methods on MSDN and also had a look for some examples of a similar thing but didn't find much.

Had anyone done anything similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest this approach. `X` and `Y` are the coordinates on the big image where you want to put the small one. You can check the `DrawImage` method overloads, there are 30 of them but I think this one best suites your case:

```
Bitmap bigBmp = new Bitmap("bigBmp.png");
Bitmap smallBmp = new Bitmap("smallBmp.png");
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bigBmp);

Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(x, y, smallBmp.Width, smallBmp.Height);
Rectangle sourceRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, smallBmp.Width, smallBmp.Height);

g.DrawImage(smallBmp, destRect, sourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
g.Dispose();
```

EDIT: Based on the comment of KvanTTT, I have decided to add another solution to the question using `DrawImageUnscaled` because it is the fastest way to draw images. There are four overloads of this method, but this one is the simplest one that matches the question.

```
Bitmap bigBmp = new Bitmap("bigBmp.png");
Bitmap smallBmp = new Bitmap("smallBmp.png");

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bigBmp);
g.DrawImageUnscaled(smallBmp, x, y);
g.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! Much appreciated, just what I was after!

Comment: @MrBeanzy This is my favorite part of the GDI+, so it was a pleasure of mine.

Comment: It's possible to improve your code with `DrawImageUnscaled` method, because of width and height of source and dest rectangles are equals.

Comment: Yes and it is the fastest way to draw images in GDI+. My point was that he should research DrawImage methods a little bit because of a lot of flexibility they offer. Thank you.